# Animation UIView from UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have one table view and one imageview, each one takes half of the screen.
I am trying to animate an image view when the user swipes on the imageview and when table cell is selected.

I use this code:

```
@interface X()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImagePreview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@end

@implementation X
- (void)handleGestureRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        [self ShowAnimation:_ImageGalaryPreview];
}
-(void)ShowAnimation:(UIImageView *)view{   
            [UIView beginAnimations: @"Slide Image" context: NULL];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
                [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:view cache:NO];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
}
@end
```

It works perfect when I call it after the swipe but when I call it from `UITableView` class instance it does not work!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self ShowAnimation:_ImageGalaryPreview];
}
```

**Can anyone tell me why ?!**

Comment: which method you mean ?

Comment: where is first piece of code located?

Comment: How did you call first piece of code? Is it located in someone method? So How did you call this method?

Comment: I don't see the point of your calling those lines of code inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method when they are free from a selected row.

Comment: I'm don't understand you , this code is use to animate an view , it's wrote by apple not by me.

Comment: OK, And you tried calling it in @interface as you explained above? :)

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov i edit the code above , see it

Comment: @Hercules did not work

Comment: @TBlue i just want to change an image from a Thumbnail table image that when the thumbnail is selected the image is change with this effect

Comment: How did it work??? It doesn't located in method. Did you try compile it in XCode, it didn't give you error?

Comment: Have you tried running it in – tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov iam sorry for the missing code , i update it above

Comment: Is your Cell clear? Isn't there some image as subView or button? Did you check that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is working?

Comment: @LescaiIonel tried it and not working

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov it's working for anything else expect the animation

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov the cell of the table just has only an thumbnail images

Comment: Then you need to check your _ImageGalaryPreview to nil. Maybe it was released.

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov the image is valid , also try change the image when cell is pressed and it is worked ,it's mean that the code is run fine but nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your calling method as given below,It will definitely work.

```
-(void)stuff
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Slide Image" context: NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:ـImagePreview cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stuff) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked after setting the controller of the two views in the same class

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass the view of tableview in place of imageView....check it works.. Enjoy

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Slide Image" context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView: tableView cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I am don't want to animate the table , i want to animate the imageView that is outside the table

Comment: where you put your imageview?

Comment: in the main view i have one table view and one image view , each one take half of the screen

Comment: ok means you want to animate imageview on click on tablecell. right?

Comment: ok use same code & in place of tableview pass imageview. & place one image in imageview to see the effects...

Comment: yes , when the cell is clicked the image is flipped and changed

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens when the user taps a table row because none of the lines in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method includes anything that is related to **indexPath.row**.  Maybe, try something like the following.

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSInteger selectedrow;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
    selectedrow = indexPath.row;
    if (indexPath.row >= 0) {
        [UIView beginAnimations: @"Slide Image" context: NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
        ...
        ...
        ImagePreview = ... [array objectAtIndex:selectedrow]...

   }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    selectedrow = -1;
}
```

Still, I don't know how your code has anything to do with UIImageView.

Comment: You'd better start with basics.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response also I solve it with this code

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stuff) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

thanks to @Hercules :)